# If $\alpha,\beta$ are two cuts then $\gamma=\alpha+\beta=\{p+q \space|\space \forall p\in \alpha,\forall q\in \beta\},$ is a cut, as well.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I was studying real analysis. I recently got to know the definition of a *cut*. The definition goes as follows:

> A set of $\alpha$ of rational numbers is said to be a cut if : (i) $\alpha\neq \emptyset, \alpha\neq \Bbb Q$ (ii) if $p\in\alpha$ and $q\in \Bbb Q$ with $q<p$ then $q\in\alpha$ (iii) if $p\in \alpha$ then $\exists q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q>p$ such that $q\in\alpha.$  The condition (ii) shows that if $\alpha$ contains a rational number then it contains all rational number preceeding it. The third condition shows that the set has no largest rational. If $\alpha=\{x\in \Bbb Q: x<r \space \text{and}\space r\in\Bbb Q\}$ then $\alpha$ is a cut and we denote $\alpha=r^*.$ We define the addition of two cuts $\alpha,\beta$ as $\gamma=\{r\in\Bbb Q| r=p+q\space \text{where }\space p\in \alpha \space \text{and}\space q\in\beta \}$ then, $\gamma$ is a cut. Now, clearly, $\alpha+0^*=\alpha.$

We define, addition of two cuts as:

> If $\alpha,\beta$ are two cuts then we define, $\gamma=\alpha+\beta=\{p+q \space|\space \forall p\in \alpha,\forall q\in \beta\}.$ It should be noted, that $\gamma $ is a cut, as well.

I am having a hard time proving $\gamma $ to be a cut. The 1st criterion for being a cut, is satisfied, since:

> Given, $\alpha, \beta $ are two cuts. Hence, $\exists q\in \Bbb Q$ such that $a,b\leq q$ for all, $a\in \alpha,b\in \beta.$ Thus, if $g\in \gamma=\alpha+\beta$ then $g= a_1+b_1$ such that $a_1\in \alpha,b_1\in \beta$ and hence $g\leq 2q,$  which proves $\gamma$ is bounded and $\gamma\neq \Bbb Q.$ $\gamma\neq\emptyset $ since, $\alpha\neq \emptyset$ and $\beta\neq \emptyset.$

We now, prove, the third criterion , i.e if $p\in \gamma$ then $\exists q\in\Bbb Q$ with $q>p$ such that $q\in\gamma$ :

> For this, we note that, if $p\in\gamma$ then $p=a+b$ such that $a\in \alpha,b\in \beta.$ Now, $\exists a_1\in \alpha$ such that $a_1>a$ and $\exists b_1\in\beta$ such that $b_1>b.$ Thus, if $p_1=a_1+b_1$, then $p_1>p$ and $p_1\in\gamma.$

But, for 2nd criterion, we need to show,  if $p\in\gamma$ and $q\in \Bbb Q$ with $q<p$ then $q\in\gamma.$ But somehow, I am unable to do so. I dont get how to prove this at all...

Comment: So you need to show this property of rationals:   if $ p = a+b$ and $p_1 < p$, there there exists $a_1<a$ and $b_1<b$ so that $p_1 = a_1+b_1$.  A special case  is: if $p_1$ is a negative rational, then it is the sum of two negative rationals.  Can you do that special case?

Comment: @GEdgar If $p=a+b$ and $p_1<p$, then, how could you assert, that there exists $a_1<a$, and $b_1<b$ so that $p_1=a_1+b_1$ ?  I know, that this statement is true, intutively since $p_1<p=a+b$. Is that sufficient ? The question I asked you, maybe , is something like "how could you assert that there is no integer between 0 and 1 ?" . The answer to this question is "no integers between 0 and 1" is simply by an extraordinarily common assertion.  I just made that example, just in case to make the situation clear. In short: Did you conclude, this, from a *general and common mathematical sense* ?

Comment: @GEdgar Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you !

Comment: Just use $h=p-p_1>0$ and $a_1=a-(h/2)<a,b_1=b-(h/2)<b$. This is using laws of arithmetic and inequalities of rationals.

Comment: Also common mathematical sense is based on standard theorems which are used so often without explicit mention.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks a lot! That completely proves the 2nd criterion! The rest part of my proof is correct, right?

Comment: Rest of the proof looks fine.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you so much!